# Idiomatic way to get labels for integer location

Tags: pandas

Say I have:

```
>> df

       col_A  col_B  col_C
row_A      0      1      2
row_B      3      4      5
row_C      6      7      8
```

If I need the integer location for the label `row_C` I have a clean API (`index.get_loc`):

```
>>> df.index.get_loc('row_C')
2
```

*But what's the right way for the inverse operation - get label for a given integer location (say, 2)?*

Of course I can use:

```
>> df.index[2]
'row_C'
```

But directly indexing the index object feels... awkward. Is there some other API method or indexing-the-index is the way to go?

Comment: I don't understand the question, why does it feel awkward? The `Index.__getitem__` was implemented so you could use the indexing syntax to get the index label. Anything wrong with it? Btw, it might help to explain the background for this question (AKA, what you're solving for) so our answers would be more informed.

Comment: I'm not saying there's something wrong with it, I'm just asking if this is the proper way. To me it feels awkward because I usually don't work on the index object directly, but through the API.

Comment: BTW - The Pandas Index [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/indexing.html) says exactly this: `Index objects: Many of these methods or variants thereof are available on the objects that contain an index (Series/DataFrame) and those should most likely be used before calling these methods directly`